# nltk.download() wont open a GUI to chose the list of downloads. It dont download data and the cursor blinks forever

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nltk, nlp

I am trying to install nltk and download the nltk data. I am trying this on python 3.7.3 and my pip is up to date. my PC is windows 10 and given by the company.

My Installation of nltk is succesfull but it wont downlaod the data. It dont give me GUI to chose downloads nor finishes the download. The cursor keeps blinking forever.

I have tried this running it as a an admin, ran it through Jupyter Notebook. Never saw the GUI at all/[image: this is my command input]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. I had to bypass web connection proxy server at my work. Instead, they added permissions for the http://files.pythonhosted.org and this worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Who knows what's going on? Maybe the download window is hidden behind other windows; I've seen that a lot. Or maybe it really doesn't come up. Either way, if you can't find the window you can largely work around the problem by using the non-GUI form of the downloader:

- `nltk.download("book")` will download all the resources you'll need while reading the book. I recommend you just run this one and move on to exploring the nltk.
- `nltk.download("all")` will download everything in the download store. Probably overkill.
- `nltk.downlead(<name>)` will download resource `<name>` (e.g., 'average_perceptron_tagger' for the tagger data, etc.) If you try to use a module and it's missing a resource, it will usually tell you what you need to download.

There are some other collective names including `all-corpora`, `popular`, and `third-party`, but the most useful ones are the above, I believe.